# Apply a pattern of objects to the outside of some other geometry

Tags: workflow

I have a pattern of objects I intend to represent in Blender as cameras (so I can simulate viewpoints from where the objects would be).  The pattern is defined by angular offsets around a circle, i.e. one at 0 degrees, one at 20 degrees, one spaced 100 degrees after that, another 120 degrees after that.

Over time, this pattern is going to need to be placed on several different imported geometries (probably from STL files).  All of them are going to be some kind of solid-of-revolution (cylindrical or conical or some tapered round body).

I would like to able to

- Define the pattern such that I could change the angular offsets between the pattern elements if needed
- Define a plane through this geometry where the pattern should lie
- Define what direction the pattern starts from (i.e. the 0-degree line)
- Have the pattern conform to the surface of the imported geometry

Is there a method of doing this?

I'm inexperienced enough with Blender that I'm not totally sure how to phrase my question, so help with that would also be appreciated.